# Mockito spy: Trying to use doReturn in spy class method but is using original method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito, spy

I have a class `EvaluationUtil.java`.

I have a method

```
protected List<LoanDemandList> someMethod(List<String> argList, String data);
```

now in unit test, I want to return a particular value when this method is called.

so i did:

```
doReturn(loanDemandDetails)
       .when(evaluationUtil)
       .someMethod(ArgumentMatchers.<String>anyList(), anyString());
```

i mocked evaluation util like this

```
evaluationUtil = spy(new EvaluationOperationUtil());
```

but whenever i call this method , it goes inside the method and it crashes, shouldnt it just return `loanDemandDetails` and not look inside the method???

Comment: Please provide ur test code in minimal.

Comment: try to replace `ArgumentMatchers.<String>anyList()` with `any(List.class)` and see if it's still using the real method. It looks like Mockito can't match the method arguments correctly and therefore invoke the real method instead

Answer (score 0):

You must not use `new` mocking your class `EvaluationOperationUtil`.

Try to mock it like this:

```
spy(EvaluationOperationUtil.class);
```

Alternatively you also could use:

```
mock(EvaluationOperationUtil.class);
```